# How to create an account for contacts in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm creating an app that manages the phonebook of the device.

In the phone, there are contact accounts like **com.google** or **com.htc.android.pcsc**.
When the user adds a new contact, the contact will be assigned to an account.

How do I **create such an account**? I'm quite unfamiliar with how the contacts account work. I would like to have a few pointers on where I should be looking this information for, if possible.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone were to create this custom accounts. You will have to create one of this using the accountManagers. That means somehow you have to write your own syncadapters and stuff like that in order to let Android recognise you as one of the accounts.

However there's a bug that restrict editing of contacts that are from this custom accounts.
Therefore, i'm not going to implement this feature in my app.